# Canon ImageClass MF8380CDW Won't Work After Upgrade to 17.10

Tags: printing, 17.10, canon

I am a total newb when it comes to Linux, so please forgive me if I screw this up.  I have been running Ubuntu Studio 17.04 with XFCE.  Over time, I developed some glitches, so I decided to reinstall.  I downloaded Ubuntu Studio 17.10, installed it, did the updates, etc.  Then it came time to print...

I am running CUPS 2.2.4 and I connect wirelessly to the printer.  I downloaded the latest 64-bit drivers from Canon and installed the three *.deb packages that came with it:  cndrvcups-common_380-1_amd64.deb, cndrvcups-ufr2-us_3.40-1_amd64.deb and cndrvcups-utility_1.00-1_amd64.deb.  These installed without issues.

The Printer dialogue sees the printer and gives it the correct IP Address.  When I go to install it, it automatically chooses "AppSocket/JetDirect network printer via DNS-SD", finds the drivers and installs the hardware. 
 When I go to print, however, the Printer State goes from "Processing" to "Processing - src = bidiCommon.c, line = 1200, err = 0¥nDEBUG2: prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.1 = 100".

If I try any of the other settings (e.g. ipps) it just hangs on "Processing".

I have another laptop which I didn't update which works just fine.

I've spent the last couple of hours Googling everything in sight, including trying to do it with Asian drivers, 32-bit drivers, etc., but no joy.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Is there a workaround?  Any help you could give would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that was an updated driver from Canon; they released it Nov 2017; folks are reporting various issues with 17.10; particularly in scanning; Canon are working on a new release for 2018; Ubuntu has LTS releases: long-term support for stability; they come out April every two years; between; Ubuntu innovate and explore with short-term releases; some distros like Mint only release LTS variants; hopefully Ubuntu 18.04 as an LTS will iron out some of these new issues; you could download the 18.04 for curiosity; run it as a live CD; see if the ufr works on it;

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded v350 from the Canon web and ran the install.sh file and now my printer is working again.  It prints PDF with out being total black and it prints word documents just fine.  Just thought someone might like to new that there is a new driver that is working now.  I have 17.10 installed but have also added some beta from 18.04 on my unit.